# @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap modal opens and closes itself

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal, ng-bootstrap

I seem to have weird issue with @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap using angular 4.3.4, bootstrap 3.3.7, jQuery 3.2.1
Here is what I have stwp-by-step

**app.module**
I have imported @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap module and used the imports NgbModule.forRoot() as they suggested in their documentation
I also have created module called "ModalModule". I have pasted its code below this

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
//import { Ng2Bs3ModalModule } from 'ng2-bs3-modal/ng2-bs3-modal';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { routing } from './app.routing';
import { CertificationComponent } from './Components/certification.component';
import {MemberBasicInformation} from './Services/memberBasicInformation.service'
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import {ModalModule} from './Modals/app.modals.module'
@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, ReactiveFormsModule, HttpModule, routing, /*Ng2Bs3ModalModule*/ NgbModule.forRoot(), ModalModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent, CertificationComponent],
    providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' }, MemberBasicInformation],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]

})
export class AppModule { }
```

**ModalModule**
I have used imports here only for NgbModule as it was suggetsed in their documentation since forRoot can only be used once.
I also have created modal component called UserNotAllowedToProceed and its code is just below this module

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import {UserNotAllowedToProceed} from "./userIsNotAllowedToProceed.modal"


@NgModule({
    imports: [NgbModule],
    declarations: [UserNotAllowedToProceed],
    entryComponents: [UserNotAllowedToProceed]
})

export class ModalModule { }
```

**UserNotAllowedToProceed modal component**

```
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";
import { NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons, NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
    selector: 'ngbd-modal-content',
    template: `
<div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">Hi there!</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="activeModal.dismiss('Cross click')">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
        <p>Hello, {{name}}!</p>
    </div>
<div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="activeModal.close('Close click')">Close</button>
    </div>
`
})

export class UserNotAllowedToProceed {
    @Input() name: string;
    constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) { }
```

So this concludes my setup process for @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap and now this is how I use it in my component

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, Input } from "@angular/core";
import { MemberBasicInformation } from "../Services/memberBasicInformation.service";
import { IMemberBasicInformationModel } from '../Models/memberBasicInformation.model';
import { NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons, NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { UserNotAllowedToProceed} from '../Modals/userIsNotAllowedToProceed.modal'
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    template: `<strong>{{data.membershipStatus}}</strong><br>
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary" (click)="displayModal();">Launch demo modal</button>
`
})

export class CertificationComponent implements OnInit{
    data: IMemberBasicInformationModel = {membershipStatus: "", firstName:"", lastName:""};
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.memberBasicInformationService.getMemberBasicData('343434343').subscribe(x => {
            this.data = x;
            console.log(this.data);
            if (this.data.membershipStatus.toLowerCase() != "Paid") {
                this.displayModal();
            }
        });
    }

    constructor(private memberBasicInformationService: MemberBasicInformation, private modalService: NgbModal) {

    }

    displayModal(): void {
        const modalRef = this.modalService.open(UserNotAllowedToProceed);
        modalRef.componentInstance.name = "world";
    }
}
```

I am calling my service OnInit and based on data I get, I am intending to popup a Modal with an information.

The problem is: Modal pops up but then it closes immediately. When I am debugging in chrome and put a breakpoint at the end of displayModal() method, I can see that modal coming up but when I continue with an execution, it closes on its own.
I tried putting the button as well and it does the same thing on button click as well (it opens a modal and then closes it)

Can someone please suggest me the solution to this problem OR suggest any alternative modal solution? I need to submit forms also using a modal so it needs to be very well behaving modal..
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap use bootstrap 4.0.0-beta and no JQuery

Comment: Eliseo, that was exactly the case.. I just upgraded to Bootstrap 4 beta  and it started working.. I also didn't have to remove the jQuery. Thanks